# How to show that this multilinear map is alternating?

Tags: permutations, multilinear-algebra

> Let $V$ be a vector space over $K$ with basis $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$.
> I already showed that for a fixed tuple $I = (i_1,\ldots,i_r)$ with $1 \le i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_r \le n$, there exists a multilinear map $\varphi_I: V^r \rightarrow K$ such that
>
> \begin{align}
> \varphi_I(e_{j_1}, \ldots, e_{j_r}) &= \begin{cases} {sgn(\sigma)} \quad \text{if there exists a permutation $\sigma$ of $[r]$ with $j_{\sigma(k)} = i_k$ for all $k \in [r]$}\\ 0 \qquad  \text{else}\end{cases}
> \end{align}
>
> for all $(j_1,\ldots,j_r) \in [n]^r$.
>
> Show that $\varphi_I$ is alternating.

I would have said that $\varphi_I$ is alternating simply because if there is a permutation $\sigma$ of $[r]$ such that $\varphi_I(e_{j_1}, \ldots, e_{j_r}) = sgn(\sigma)$, then, as we know from linear algebra, transposing $e_{j_k}$ and $e_{j_l}$ just changes the sign of $\sigma$. (We may assume that $e_{j_1}, \ldots, e_{j_r}$ are distinct, otherwise $\varphi_I = 0$ and the claim is clearly true then.) However, my instructor said that there is some trap in this exercise, so is there something I am overlooking?

Comment: Say $1,2 \notin I$. Then the permutations $(34)$ is odd but $(12)(34)$ is even.

Comment: How can an element of $K$ be a permutation?

Comment: @TedShifrin: Sorry, I fixed the typos.

Comment: @CyclotomicField: Sorry, but I do not get your argument. My permutation $\sigma$ is only defined over $[r]$.

Comment: @3nondatur You mentioned the trap so I'm looking for one. Have you already proven that alternating maps are antisymmetric?

Comment: I don’t know if it’s a trap or not, but you have to argue for any pair of vectors, not just the given basis vectors.

Comment: @TedShifrin: I think this is the point, I do not see how to extend the alternating property to general vectors.

Comment: @CyclotomicField: Yes, we have already done that.

Comment: OK. So try to work this out with $r=2$ (the general case just has extra notation, no extra ideas).